# Unity2D как просчитать траекторию прыжка

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр, 2d

Нужно просчитать траекторию движения персонажа после прыжка, чтобы именно к концу его движения заспавнить платформу, вообще ума не приложу как это сделать.

Сила прыжка допустим всегда будет постоянна, но скорость движения объекта постоянно увеличиватся, и высота откуда будет прыгать объект рандомна(скажем это будет случайно сгенерированные транплины), и вот надо просчитать траекторию прыжка

Методом тыка сделать фиксированное растоянние не вариант, так как высота транплина рандомна и скорость постоянно увеличивается

А как просчитать силу прыжка если мы используем RigiBody2D?
Или может быть лучше просчитавать это дело, и двигать объект через transform, а для расчет траектории испольовать классические формулы траектория движения тела брошенного под углом к горизонту?
[image]

У кого какие мысли подскажите, и как это дело можно оформить под с#

Comment: Не особо понятно, зачем спавнить какую-то платформу в конце траектории. Мало того, где этот ваш конец траектории? Тело не будет замедляться, мало того, под действием гравитации оно будет разгоняться. Так в какой точке траектории вам нужно разместить платформу и зачем?

Comment: @selya Предположим у нас приложение под типа раннера, и после каждого прыжка с рандомного транплина гг должен призмемлятся на платформу, допустим если прыгнет слишком поздно, то не долетает и падает в пропасть, вот допустим и пытаюсь расчитать эту траекторию, чтобы по ней определять где заспавнить платформу, или допустим по этой идеальной траектории заспавнить коины и тд, но как в коде это должно выглядить с применением формул ума не приложу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Брать координаты персонажа [playerTransform.position](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.html), сравнивать вертикальную координату playerTransform.position.y с уровнем возникновения платформы, при достижении нужной вам разницы размещать платформу (playerTransform.position.x,platformY). Соответственно расстояние до предполагаемой платформы сравниваете при приземлении, а не на "взлете", и сравниваете операторами >, >=, < или <= [(не используйте для сравнения float операторы == и !=)](https://habrahabr.ru/post/112953/,). И двигается игрок Transform.position, Move или AddForce в данном случае будет неважно.

Comment: Знаками битового сдвига?)

Comment: Смешно. Чтобы float == и != не сравнивал, а то мало ли...

Comment: а, у вас там знаки через пробел. На мобилке они слились в shift assignment. Может поставите их так, чтобы больше не возникало вопросов у таких, как я?)

Comment: @Mike а что если мне нужно размещать платформу не то что при взлете, а за несколько экранов раньше, чтобы просто напросто это не происходило внезапно, а заранее была размещена?

Comment: @Mike а так вариант очень подходит, и выглядит намного проще чем я пытался придумать, спасибо